# Prove that $(I(X),\rho_\infty)$ is compact set.

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

> $I(X)$ - group of isometries of metric space $(X,\rho)$
>
> $(X,\rho)$ - compact set

I should prove that $(I(X),\rho_\infty)$ - compact set

What should I use for proof this statement?

Answer (score 1):

How about Arzela-Ascoli? A subset of the space of continuous functions on a compact set is compact if it is uniformly equicontinuous. I think uniform equicontinuity holds rather trivially for the set of all isometries, which themselves, self-evidently, are a subset of the continuous functions on X.

Comment: Need to show it's closed too.

Comment: Right. So you have additionally to show that the uniform limit of isometries is an isometry. That is surely true, and should not be too difficult.